# Django CreateView not sending form

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

This view is not sending the form. I don't know why. I can see it is not sending the form cause I'm printing the `context` at the end of the `get_context_data` function.

```
class CrearFeralSpirit(CreateView):

    template_name = "hisoka/crear_feral_spirit.html"
    model = FeralSpirit
    fields = ['tipo', 'nombre', 'url']

    def form_valid(self, form):

        fireball = Fireball.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        form.instance.fireball = fireball

        return super(CrearFeralSpirit, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CrearFeralSpirit, self).get_context_data()
        fireball = Fireball.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug_fireball'])

        context['fireball'] = fireball
        print context  # Here I print the context, no form in it.
        return context
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the `*args` and `*kwargs` to parent class as well when you call `super`? `context = super(CrearFeralSpirit, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: True, thanks, that worked.  If you want you could write the answer and I'll accept it. Also .... I don't understand why it worked, when I call the `super` , it calls the `get_context_data` without the `args` and `kwargs`, but why does it need the `args` and `kwargs` in the first place? isn't the `form` supposed to be there already? At what point the `form` is added to the `context`.. confused I am. :P

Comment: I updated with an answer. I couldn't check what django does exactly with those parameters, I might update my answer later when I have access to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I put in the comment, you forgot to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the parent class when you call `super`, so it should be:

```
context = super(CrearFeralSpirit, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

`*args` and `**kwargs` are the parameters defined by django `get_context_data` and they are definitely used inside django. If you don't pass them to the parent class, django is lack of certain information that's needed. Without them django couldn't construct the form thus your context doesn't have any form.